# Discord.py - Await for user's message

Tags: python, discord.py

so right now I'm trying to create a type of application bot and right now the check I used for the bot doesn't allow the user to move onto the next question. There is no traceback so it's something with the check I defined.

```py
@commands.command()
  @commands.has_role("Realm OP")
  async def block(self, ctx, user: discord.User):
    DMchannel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    author = ctx.message.author
    mentions = [role.mention for role in ctx.message.author.roles if role.mentionable]
    channel2 = str(channel.name)
    channel = channel2.split('-')
    if len(channel2) == 2: # #real-emoji
      realm, emoji = channel
    else: # #realm-name-emoji  
      realm, emoji = channel[0], channel[-1]
      realmName = realm.replace("-" , " ")
      realmName1 = realmName.lower()
    rolelist = []
    print(realmName1)
    a = solve(realmName1)
    print(a)
    realmName2 = str(a) + " OP"
    print(realmName2)
    check_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name= realmName2)
    if check_role not in ctx.author.roles:
      return await ctx.send('You do not own this channel')

    else:
      await ctx.send("You own this channel!")
      def check(m):
        return m.channel == channel and m.author != self.bot.user
        
      await DMchannel.send("Please fill out the questions in order to block the user!")

      await DMchannel.send("User's Gamertag: (If you don't know, try using the >search command to see if they have any previous records!) ")
      blocka1 = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

      await DMchannel.send("Reason for block:")
      blocka2 = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
```

Right now the bot doesn't do anything after the user responds to the first question and there is no traceback.

Any help or suggestions would help greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check isn't returning anything. It's supposed to `return` either `True` or `False`. This means your `wait_for` will never end (as the `check` never returns `True`), so it will never ask the next question.

```py
def check(m):
  return m.channel == channel and m.author != self.bot.user
```

EDIT:

Your `channel` is the `ctx.channel`, while your bot waits for answers in DM. Assuming you answer your bot in DM as well, this means your `check` will never pass, as `m.channel` never equals `channel`.

```py
def check(m):
  return m.guild is None and m.author == ctx.author
```

This checks if a message was sent in DM (`Guild` is `None`), and if it was a DM by the original author.

Comment: Still didn't change anything, I added the `return` and the bot still doesn't proceed to the next question.

Comment: I just tested this & it works so the problem should be elsewhere in your code. Is there any more you can show?

Comment: Updated the main post.

Comment: Maybe it's the channel or something?

Comment: The `channel` variable is `ctx.channel` (as in - a GUILD CHANNEL), while your bot asks the questions in DM. I assume you're trying to answer your bot in DM so it never passes your `check`, as `m.channel` will never be equal to `ctx.channel`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @pjones123 No. Discord overrides the `eq` method of both, so that comparing a `Member` to a `User` is possible. They are equal if the user's `id` are the same. Source: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/member.py#L188

Comment: Deleted my comment. Sorry!